# Angularjs problems appending table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, append

I am learning Angularjs (I am still very fresh). I am trying to add a row to a table on a button click. I am basing my code from this tutorial -  http://plnkr.co/edit/64e1nGNkc4vYynEY6IQz?p=preview

My code appends the content but it leaves out the  and  tags and it is adding  tags. Furthermore, I tried appending just a simple string like 'test' and it adds  tags to the string...why does it add tags I didn't include?

My html -

```
      <div ng-controller="growingTable">
        <div ng-controller="incomeController">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
              <td>Account</td>
              <td>Budget</td>
              <td>%</td>
              <td>Enter Amount</td>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td>%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
                <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Account" ng-model="r.account"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="r.funding.startingEstimate"y placeholder="Budgeted"></td>
                <td class="warning">20%</td>
                <td>{{funding.needed}}</td>
                <td class="warning">$500</td>
                <td class="warning">50%</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"ng-click="addField()">ADD FIELD</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('incomeController', function($scope) {
 $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
 computeNeeded = function() {
$scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate / 100;
};
$scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
});

app.controller('growingTable', function($scope){
$scope.rows = [];

$scope.addField = function(){
    $scope.rows.push({        
    });
}    
});
```

This is the code that gets appending after the row in the table. What happened to the table elements? And why does it add the span tags??

```
<input class="form-control ng-scope" placeholder="Account">
<input class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Budgeted" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
<span class="ng-scope ng-binding">20%$50050%</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? There was a fix that concerned code using templates with table element tags (cf. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/31c450bcee53d0a3827b7e0a611e9013b2496506). But to resolve your problem, see if upgrading to a new version does the trick. By the way, doing DOM manipulation in your controller is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this would be to create an array in your controller and us ng-repeat to generate the table. That way, your 'Add Field' function would just need to create a new element on the array and Angular would deal with updating the html for you.

For example your html would be:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="growingTable">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
        <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Account" ng-model="r.account"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="r.startingEstimate" placeholder="Budgeted"></td>
        <td class="warning">20%</td>
        <td>{{r.needed}}</td>
        <td class="warning">$500</td>
        <td class="warning">50%</td>
     </tr>
</table>

 <button ng-click="addField()">ADD FIELD</button>
        <br>
           {{rows}}
 </div>
```

And your app would look like:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('growingTable', function($scope){
$scope.rows = [];

$scope.addField = function(){
    $scope.rows.push({
        account : '',
        startingEstimate : '',
        needed : ''
    });
}

});
```

You'll find a working version http://jsfiddle.net/y53Yd/

Comment: Thank you. Works great. Can you tell me why what I was doing before removed the table tags?

Comment: Also...is there simple way to keep each field separate from each other? ie, I want to do data calculation in each seperate field....so if they are in a repeat like that, won't each field do the same calculations?

Comment: Can you give me an idea of what your calculating - it's probably easier to demonstrate!

Comment: could you not just calculate in directly in the view? EG instead of <td>{{r.needed}}</td> just do <td>{{r.startingEstimate / 100}}</td>?

Comment: Yeah but when I add another field, any number put in the fields repeats in every row.

Comment: That's strange - each item generated by ng-repeat should be a separate entity. Is there any chance you could put what you've got so far in a jsfiddle so we can figure out where the  problem is?